# play framework bootstrap3 tags input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, playframework

I am attempting to use the following items in conjunction:

[bootstrap tags input](https://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)

[play-boostrap-3](https://github.com/adrianhurt/play-bootstrap3)

For the most part, it works pretty well. The only issues I have are the following:

1. the span with the 'X' does not appear on the tags, which becomes a problem if the user wants to remove the first out of 2+ elements, as the only way around this right now is to backspace all elements and start over.
2. The styling of the input field itself is much different than it appears on the tags input website.

The attached screenshot below shows how it appears for me:

[image: tags-input-render]

It also seems that the input field itself moves over to the side as tags are entered, whereas on the example page the tags remain inside the input field itself.

Here is the twirl template code for this page pictured (only included the form section for brevity):

```
@helper.form(action = routes.ResponseController.saveInterests()) {

    <h4>Hobbies</h4>
    @b3.text(interestsForm("watch"),'_label -> "My favorite sports/TV Series/movies to watch are...",'placeholder->"e.g. True Detective,NFL Football", Symbol("data-role")->"tagsinput",'_class -> "tagsinput",Symbol("data-hint") ->"Hit backspace to delete an entry")
    @b3.text(interestsForm("sport"),'_label -> " My favorite sports/activities to do are ...", 'placeholder->"e.g. badminton, swimming",Symbol("data-role")->"tagsinput",'_class -> "tagsinput",Symbol("data-hint") ->"Hit backspace to delete an entry")
    @b3.text(interestsForm("games"),'_label -> "My favorite games are...", 'placeholder->"e.g. Yu-Gi-Oh, Fallout",Symbol("data-role")->"tagsinput",'_class -> "tagsinput",Symbol("data-hint") ->"Hit backspace to delete an entry")
    @b3.text(interestsForm("interest"),'_label -> "Other favorite things I like are...",'placeholder->"e.g. cooking,politics,coffee", Symbol("data-role")->"tagsinput",'_class -> "tagsinput",Symbol("data-hint") ->"Hit backspace to delete an entry")
    @b3.text(interestsForm("uniqueInt"),'_label -> "Something I like, but none of my friends like are...",'placeholder->"e.g. Mac Miller,mimosas", Symbol("data-role")->"tagsinput",'_class -> "tagsinput",Symbol("data-hint") ->"Hit backspace to delete an entry")
    @b3.text(interestsForm("wan2try"),'_label -> "I always wanted to try...",'placeholder->"e.g. skydiving, ethiopian food", Symbol("data-role")->"tagsinput",'_class -> "tagsinput",Symbol("data-hint") ->"Hit backspace to delete an entry")
    <h4>General</h4>
    <p><i>No ideas? Think of your favorite music, sports, books, TV series, movies, games, art, food & drinks,
        computer & technology, fashion, cars, spirituality, politics ...</i></p>

    @b3.text(interestsForm("lookingFor"),'_label -> "I’m looking for people for...",'placeholder->"e.g. beach volleyball", Symbol("data-role")->"tagsinput",'_class -> "tagsinput",Symbol("data-hint") ->"Hit backspace to delete an entry")
    @b3.text(interestsForm("help"),'_label -> "I need some help with...",'placeholder->"e.g. fixing my car", Symbol("data-role")->"tagsinput",'_class -> "tagsinput",Symbol("data-hint") ->"Hit backspace to delete an entry")
    @b3.text(interestsForm("learnAbout"),'_label -> "I’d like to learn / get better at...",'placeholder->"e.g. iOS development,scala", Symbol("data-role")->"tagsinput",'_class -> "tagsinput",Symbol("data-hint") ->"Hit backspace to delete an entry")
    @b3.text(interestsForm("expert"),'_label -> "I'm really good at...",'placeholder->"e.g electric guitar,C++", Symbol("data-role")->"tagsinput",'_class -> "tagsinput",Symbol("data-hint") ->"Hit backspace to delete an entry")
    @b3.text(interestsForm("beginner"),'_label -> "I just started learning / doing...",'placeholder->"e.g. paddleboard yoga,rock climbing", Symbol("data-role")->"tagsinput",'_class -> "tagsinput",Symbol("data-hint") ->"Hit backspace to delete an entry")
    @b3.text(interestsForm("willing_to_teach"),'_label -> "Things I’m willing to teach / help out others with are...",'placeholder->"e.g. learning spanish,knitting", Symbol("data-role")->"tagsinput",'_class -> "tagsinput",Symbol("data-hint") ->"Hit backspace to delete an entry")
    @b3.buttonType("submit", 'class -> "btn btn-material-light-blue-700 pull-right btn-large"){Next}
}
```

And here is the small bit of javascript to edit the widths of the tag input fields:

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
            $("div.bootstrap-tagsinput > input").attr("style","width: 33em !important;");
    </script>
```

Comment: Without an example will be hard to help you.

Comment: sorry, i edited and added the relevant code bits